# PHP-FPM static max_children amount doesn't seem to matter much during stress tests

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, mysql, php, php-fpm

I've been stress testing **PHP-FPM** set up as **static** using **wrk**, with **NGINX** running on **Ubuntu Server 22.04** for the past few days, writing down results for every scenario. When I look at them, it seems to me, the amount of max_children doesn't seem to matter much. And this got me puzzled, since all the articles on the web suggest various methods of calculating the right amount to max out the performance. But none of them really apply to my case, as it seems.

I run this on **4 cores** with **4 GB RAM**.
I have a test php script that pulls and prints around **11k** of lines from **MySQL** table, **1 MB** large document.

The average process size is **12.5 MB**
The results are identical for max_children **10**, **50**, **100**. With **200**, the server gets overloaded.

This got me thinking, maybe it's related to the number of cores, but no, with only **4 max_children**, the results are lower than the previously mentioned, although not by much. 8 max_children is already nearly identical.

All the scenarios (4, 8, 10, 50, 100) for max_children can handle up to 500 connections before time outs and drop outs start to occur.

Can someone please explain to me, how is that possible? What am I missing?

> **EDIT:**
>
> As per Rick's suggestion I tried to ramp up MySQL max_connections to
> 351 from the default 151, after calculating the max amount from the
> available RAM. This didn't affect the results at all so I went to
> square 1 and started testing from **1 max_children** and **1 wrk
> thread** upwards and while doing so, encountered more behavior I
> couldn't explain.
>
> The max_children that only makes sense seems to be **6**. Nothing over
> that limit will bring any extra requests.
>
> While testing only single thread **wrk requests** the CPU load kept
> rising with every **php-fpm children** added and stayed the same, no
> matter the amount of connections thrown at it from wrk.
>
> The ceiling for average total requests for a **30s long** stress test is
> around **11371** requests. This can be reached since **6 max_children**
> and seems to be related to CPU load, that reaches 90% during this
> peak. No more requests can be reached, no matter the amount of
> max_children.
>
> A rather strange behavior occurred when testing on **4 threads**. The
> results for equal number of connections are lower than single thread
> stress test, but the latency is lower, which makes sense I guess. But
> when it comes to **CPU load**, anything below **8 connections** has
> around **70% load**, no matter the **max_children**, but once the
> amount of connections go one above, to **9**, the CPU load increases
> drastically, by over **20%** with higher amounts of max_children. The
> only thing that comes to my mind is it must be related to the amount
> of CPU cores, 4 in this case, that can only handle 2 simultaneous
> connections per core. Other than that I'm lost.
>
> My assumption is, at least in my case, the bottleneck is the **CPU**. I
> never run out of memory. I have high limits set both for **NGINX** and
> **MySQL** connections. I would still appreciate if this could be confirmed and perhaps further explained. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

- The important metric is "connections per hour".  This is the "capacity" of your system.  Stress testing measures "simultaneous connections", which is mostly irrelevant.
- The number of cores is rarely the limiting factor in the setup you describe.  On the other hand, if you do run out of CPU oomph, we should look at the slow queries to see what can be optimized.
- If a connection takes only 20ms to process a page, then none of the knobs you are tweaking matter much.  The connections are coming and going fast enough.  If you can shrink the 20 to 15, you can handle 20/15 times as many "connections per hour".  That is, by improving the code, each "active" connection finishes faster.
- Stress testing generally tests how rapidly new connections can be created before the system overloads and appears to "crash".  Such a "crash" is really lots of processes stumbling over each other trying to share the same resources (CPU, locks, ram, cache, network, I/O, whatever).
- MySQL is designed to share *evenly*.  This means that the connections are stumbling over each other.  The real cure is to push the problem *up* the stack.  That is, limit the number of connections, preferably at the webserver layer.
- MySQL can handle only a few dozen *active* connections simultaneously.  `max_connections` includes "Sleep" connections (not running SQL).  Your numbers showed that 100 did not "crash", but I suspect that response time was already suffering.
- If you set the web server's "max children" to more than MySQL's "max_connections", a stress test may find that the web server is sometimes getting "unable to connect".
- In the real system (not just the stress test), it is likely to be better to keep "max children" lower than "max_connections" since the browsers understand what to do with that error.

(More)

- "calculating the max amount..of RAM" -- This is futile.  There is no adequate formula for MySQL.
- What is a "work thread"?  In MySQL, watch `Threads_running`; if it gets over about a dozen, MySQL is about as busy as it can be.  If that number gets much higher, the threads stumble over each other, and things actually *slow down*.
- `top`, `htop`, etc are ways to watch the number of cores in use.  I almost never see all cores busy, even on a very busy server.  Other resources are usually hit first.
- If CPU is the bottleneck, we need to look at the queries and the schema.
- Users want "low latency".  Adding too many threads leads to poor latency.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, Rick. Simultaneous connections are exactly what I'm tuning the server to. The main load will come from API calls from mobile applications, one of which is a social network (a small one, but still). I will look into the MySQL max_connections as suggested and see if that is the bottleneck (makes sense it has to be something outside of PHP, when the numbers don't differ at all for various settings).

Comment: I have made some further testing and described the results in detail in an edit to the original post. Could you tell me something more with regard to the edit please?

Comment: I added more...